# How set background drawable programmatically in Android

Tags: java, android, background, drawable

### To set Background:

```
RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.background);
layout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ready);
```

Is the best way to do it?

Comment: Thank you! your question and all helpful answers helped me set the background resource of an image button inside a **widget**. here's a sample code in case someone is interested: `remoteViews.setInt(R.id.btn_start,"setBackgroundResource",  R.drawable.ic_button_start);`

Comment: Kotlin Solution for whom may need : https://stackoverflow.com/a/54495750/6247186

Answer (score 598, accepted):

`layout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ready);` is correct.
Another way to achieve it is to use the following:

```
final int sdk = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
if(sdk < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
    layout.setBackgroundDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.ready) );
} else {
    layout.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.ready));
}
```

But I think the problem occur because you are trying to load big images.
 [Here](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html) is a good tutorial how to load large bitmaps.

**UPDATE:
 getDrawable(int ) deprecated in API level 22** 
`getDrawable(int )` is now deprecated in API level 22.
You should use the following code from the support library instead:

```
ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.ready)
```

If you refer to the source code of [ContextCompat.getDrawable](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.0.1_r1/android/support/v4/content/ContextCompat.java#ContextCompat.getDrawable%28android.content.Context%2Cint%29), it gives you something like this:

```
/**
 * Return a drawable object associated with a particular resource ID.
 * <p>
 * Starting in {@link android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES#LOLLIPOP}, the returned
 * drawable will be styled for the specified Context's theme.
 *
 * @param id The desired resource identifier, as generated by the aapt tool.
 *            This integer encodes the package, type, and resource entry.
 *            The value 0 is an invalid identifier.
 * @return Drawable An object that can be used to draw this resource.
 */
public static final Drawable getDrawable(Context context, int id) {
    final int version = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
    if (version >= 21) {
        return ContextCompatApi21.getDrawable(context, id);
    } else {
        return context.getResources().getDrawable(id);
    }
}
```

More details on [ContextCompat](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/ContextCompat.html)

As of API 22, you should use the `getDrawable(int, Theme)` method instead of getDrawable(int).

**UPDATE:**
If you are using the support v4 library, the following will be enough for all versions.

```
ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.ready)
```

You will need to add the following in your app build.gradle

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0' # or any version above
```

Or using ResourceCompat, in any API like below:

```
import android.support.v4.content.res.ResourcesCompat;
ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), R.drawable.name_of_drawable, null);
```

Comment: 'getDrawable(int)' is deprecated.

Comment: Hey, I am trying to do a task only if the background image of an image button is a certain drawable resource. How can I compare... I've tried `if(buttonBackground.equals(R.drawable.myDrawable))` where `Drawable buttonBackground = myButton.getBackground();`I get this error:  http://snag.gy/weYgA.jpg

Comment: You would also need `myActivity.getTheme()` for the latest version of method, instead of null parameter: `myView.setBackground(
      getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.my_background,
          activity.getTheme()));`

Comment: or you can use `AppCompatResources.getDrawable(this.getContext(), resId)` instead, Google already implemented it to in `AppCompat*` widget/view, e.g: `android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckBox`

Answer (score 120):

Try this:

```
layout.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.ready));
```

and for API 16<:

```
layout.setBackgroundDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.ready));
```

Comment: but this is the same thing Ahmad :)

Comment: ah ok, then I would refere to Lazy Ninjas answer.

Comment: You do not need `getResources().getDrawable()`. The correct code is `layout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ready);` just like the OP used. The issue here comes from the size of the bitmap.

Comment: setBackground is API level 16 or above only.

Answer (score 20):

```
RelativeLayout relativeLayout;  //declare this globally
```

now, inside any function like onCreate, onResume

```
relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);  
relativeLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.view); //or whatever your image is
setContentView(relativeLayout); //you might be forgetting this
```

Answer (score 12):

I'm using a minSdkVersion 16 and targetSdkVersion 23.
The following is working for me, it uses

```
ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.drawable);
```

Instead of using:

```
layout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ready);
```

Rather use:

```
layout.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.ready));
```

`getActivity()` is used in a fragment, if calling from a activity use `this`.

Answer (score 11):

If you use AndroidX, you should use:

```
AppCompatResources.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.your_drawable)
```

Previous methods listed are deprecated.

Answer (score 9):

You can also set the background of any Image:

```
View v;
Drawable image=(Drawable)getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.img);
(ImageView)v.setBackground(image);
```

Comment: this solve my problem, but I need to implement the `(.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)` inner the code

Comment: This is deprecated now

Answer (score 3):

```
setBackground(getContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.green_rounded_frame));
```

Comment: Ad explanation, please.

Answer (score 2):

If your backgrounds are in the drawable folder right now try moving the images from drawable to drawable-nodpi folder in your project. This worked for me, seems that else the images are rescaled by them self..

Comment: Well if you haven't got a copy of the images you need to use in the project in HD quality, why let android rescale them to crappy quality by using the normal drawable folder. And even do the question is old, if it still pops up in Google than posting something new in it is ok imho.

Answer (score 1):

Use [butterknife](http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/) to bind the drawable resource to a variable by adding this to the top of your class (before any methods).

```
@Bind(R.id.some_layout)
RelativeLayout layout;
@BindDrawable(R.drawable.some_drawable)
Drawable background;
```

then inside one of your methods add

```
layout.setBackground(background);
```

That's all you need

Answer (score 1):

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
     layout.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ready));
else if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1)
     layout.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ready));
else
     layout.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.ready));
```

Answer (score 1):

Give a try to `ViewCompat.setBackground(yourView, drawableBackground)`

Answer (score 1):

try this.

```
 int res = getResources().getIdentifier("you_image", "drawable", "com.my.package");
 preview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.preview);
 preview.setBackgroundResource(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
Drawable thumb = ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), R.mipmap.cir_32);
mSeekBar.setThumb(thumb);
```

Answer (score -1):

Inside the app/res/**your_xml_layout_file**.xml

1. Assign a name to your parent layout.
2. Go to your MainActivity and find your RelativeLayout by calling the findViewById(R.id."given_name").
3. Use the layout as a classic Object, by calling the method setBackgroundColor().