# how to add background image to preferences activity in android?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

i am new to custom PreferencesActivity, i am working since three days to get custom preferences, what i want is i want a preferences screen with background image and  color views for every preference cell, 
1) i had tried with res/xml/preferences.xml, but i cant create background image i had tried with many solutions but i couldn't find any solution.
2)i had tried with res/layout/pref.xml, but i couldn't able to save the settings of preferences

please help me in creating such type of preferencesActivity with background image

Comment: There's no putImage() or getImage() in Preferences, nor similar methods. So, **store the path to the image as a string**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see [How set background drawable programmatically in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12523005/android-set-background-drawable-programmatically)

and save this link http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html