# How to set background to views programmatically?

Tags: android, android-layout

I added a `View` to layout programmatically to draw a horizontal line.

Below is java code.

```
  // I want to add a view to ll
  LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.main);

  LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
  View view = new View(this);
  ll.addView(view);
  view.setLayoutParams(params);

  // this method does not work.
  view.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.division_line));
```

my `division_line.xml` in /drawable is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <stroke android:color="#800400"
            android:width="2dp"/>
</shape>
```

I tried to apply `division_line.xml` to `View` but it doesn't work. What method should I use?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android set background drawable programmatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12523005/android-set-background-drawable-programmatically)

Comment: By the way, you can use `setBackgroundResource()` method: `view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.division_line);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

view.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.division_line))
instead of 
view.setBackgroundDrawable(...)

and keep in mind that first 2dp isn't much and you are adding a view with no layout properties so its size is 0px x 0px

you can do so in code: 
view.setLayoutParams(new AbsListView.LayoutParams(300, 300));

Comment: Why should I use`setLayoutParams()` though I set a width of drawable in `division_line.xml`?

Comment: The width in the drawable only descripes the drawables width, but if you don't set any width on your layout which uses the drawable you won't see anything because it's not visible, im sorry.