# How to change ImageButton background for a while

Tags: android, handler, runnable

I have an ImageButton (btnOpen), and I want to change its background, but just for a second, for example.

I know the method to do this (I use `btnOpen.setBackgroundResource(my_resource);` ), but how can I do that without making my UI non-responsive?

What's the best and simplest way, do I have to use something like Handler or runOnUIThread?

Thanks for help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Load image from url](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5776851/load-image-from-url)

Comment: In my opinion a good way to do this is an AsyncTask. Load the images in 'doInBackground' and set it in 'onPostExecute'.

Answer (score 0):

One way to deal with this is to preload your ressource programmatically using a Handler.

I think this post can help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/12523109/665823

But usually if the UI is getting block by loading a single image ressource this means your ressource is too big. Try checking this out first.

Answer (score 0):

Use a handler

```
new android.os.Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
      imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.something);
  }
}, 1000);
```