# Programmatically setting TextView background

Tags: java, android, android-drawable

I've defined a background for my `TextView`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape= "rectangle"  >
    <solid android:color="#000"/>
    <stroke android:width="1dp"  android:color="#ff9"/>
</shape>
```

Now I'm trying to set it to my `TextView` programmatically:

```
textview.setBackground((Drawable)findViewById(R.drawable.cellborder));
```

This isn't working though, it's telling me it can't cast a `View` as a `Drawable`. Is there another way to do this?

Comment: Have you tried setBackgroundDrawable()?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use

```
getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.cellborder);
```

which will return a `Drawable`.

If you use `findViewById()` it will try to find a `View` in the View Hierarchy and return that. A `View` is not a `Drawable`, so you can't cast it.

Answer (score 5):

If you want backwards compatibility then use the following:

```
textView.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(MainActivity.this, R.drawable.cellborder));
```

Replace `MainActivity.this` with the name of the activity from where are you calling these methods.

If you call `textView.setBackground(...)` from Pijamas activity then do the following:

```
textView.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(Pijamas.this, R.drawable.cellborder));
```

Answer (score 2):

try to set drawable like this

```
textview.setBackgroundDrawable( getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.cellborder) );
```

visit for more help.
[set background drawable programmatically in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12523109/5202007)

Comment: This method is deprecated. use instead `tv.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(QuestionActivity.this, R.drawable.bg_shadow));`