# Android, can't see my app background image

Tags: android, background-image, drawable, xml-drawable

I have a problem with the background image of my app, I have set it with android:background="@drawable/image_name" and, on the preview of android studio, works fine, but, when i'm running the app, I can't see the image but only a white background, someone can help me?

here's my xml

```
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/splash"
tools:context="com.example.ivan.posteggiaTI.LoginActivity">

<com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
    android:id="@+id/login_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_above="@+id/editTextLoginEmail"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="48dp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editTextLoginEmail"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/login_edit_text"
    android:hint="Email"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
    android:paddingBottom="0dp"
    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="0dp"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="22dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/editTextLoginPassword"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editTextLoginPassword"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/login_edit_text"
    android:hint="Password"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:paddingBottom="0dp"
    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
    android:paddingRight="15dp"
    android:paddingTop="0dp"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/textViewRegister"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="34dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewRegister"
    android:layout_width="160dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/button_blue_login"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:text="Registrati"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textViewLogin"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/textViewLogin" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewLogin"
    android:layout_width="160dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/button_blue_login"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:text="Login"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:layout_marginBottom="27dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" /></RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: tried this code, working fine on my device, lollipop

Comment: Try to change background from code programmatically like here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12523005/how-set-background-drawable-programmatically-in-android

Comment: which code? You forgot it...

Comment: @DavidBalas i tryed in this way 
`RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relativeLayoutLogin);
        relativeLayout.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.splash));` 
but doesn't work

Comment: it didn't work because you didn't name your RelativeLayout id as relativeLayoutLogin, you need to add id attribute..

Comment: Can you tell me the size of splash image and in which drawable folder you kept it?

Comment: Image available in all drawable folder or not ?

Comment: Yes, the image is available in all drawable folder, the dimesion of the images are the same
752x1336
502x829
377x669
252x447
@DavidBalas I have add the id attribute on the relative layout before try

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sometimes android studio doesnt install the new apk while running. It bring the previous activity to front.

Follow the steps.

1. Make sure you have the image in drawable folder.
2. Rebuild the application. Build->Rebuild application
3. Uninstall the application from the emulator or phone(Testing device).
4. Run the application.

When you put your image in drawable folder. Aptly choose for which screen density you want which picture.

As there are drawable-ldpi,drawable-mdpi,drawable-hdpi etc... and a normal drawable folder. If android studio cant find a image in these qualifier drawable folder then it will look up in the normal drawable folder.

Answer (score 0):

Use an `ImageView` as the first element in your `RelativeLayout`. Then, set your `drawable` to `src` of the `ImageView` and set `scaleType` to `fitXY` so that your background is shown properly.