# Programmatically changing background

Tags: java, android

I have this code that changes the background when you click a button however, I want to change the background every 10 seconds, and I want to switch between files img1.png, img2.png and img3.png and when the cycle is completed start all over again. Thanks in advance.
Here is the code:
In  'MainActivity.java'

```
package lucas.app_2001;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    Button button;
    LinearLayout mainLayout;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mainLayout=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.myLayout);
        button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                mainLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.yellowgradient);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

'MainActivity.xml':

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/myLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="64dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="71dp"
        android:text="Shout!" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: take a look at this SO question: [How to set background drawable programmatically...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12523005)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this way:

```
private Handler mHandler;
private Runnable mRunnable;
private int i = 0;
```

**MainActivity.java**:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    Button button;
    LinearLayout mainLayout;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mainLayout=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.myLayout);
        button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                mainLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.yellowgradient);
            }
        });

        mHandler = new Handler();
        mRunnable = new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
             i++;
             if(i==1){
             mainLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.image_one);
              }else if(i==2){
             mainLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.image_two);
              }else if(i==3){
             mainLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.image_three);
               i ==0;
              }

             mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable , 10000);
            }
         }; 
        mHandler .post(mRunnable);
    }
}
```

on **onStop()**:

```
if(mHandler!=null){
  mHandler.removeCallbacks(mRunnable);
}
```

**Done**

Comment: It crashes on the emulator... Any idea why?

Comment: On **onCreate** I get this error: Missing Super Call  Some methods, such as View#onDetachedFromWindow, require that you also call the super implementation as part of your method.

Comment: added  this line of code ´super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);´ but it still crashes

Comment: @lucasrodriguez, I have edited my answer, please check it. You have to put your code on onclick of Button.

Comment: the thing is I don't want to use a button at all

Comment: @lucasrodriguez, you want on start of activity ?

Comment: Yes when the app opens i want it to display an image and then start changing every 10 s

Answer (score 0):

Use a `while` loop to repeat.

To delay it for 10 seconds try something like this:

```
//wait 10 seconds
        Button.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                Button.setClickable(true);                        
            }
        }, 10000);
```

Comment: The thing is I don't want a button I just want to be able to change between the images with out the users interaction

Comment: Im sry, then you should use a handler and put the code in onCreate