# Simple Task, Strange Answer

Tags: android, android-studio

I must be overthinking this one, but when I am trying to change the background of a relative layout `onClick`I am getting the error `setBackground` in `view` cannot be set to `int`.
Here is some of the code below:

```
btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (!check) {
                check = true;
                relativeLayout.setBackground(R.drawable.bg);
                                 ^^^Apparently this is considered an int???
            } else {
                relativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                check = false;
            }
        }
    });
```

Some things to note:

- The relative layout is attributed to a class that extends a fragment
- `Btn1` and `relativeLayout` were correctly identified outside of this small section of code. 
  I tried looking around the website for similar problems but could only find one. The solution was to use `Bitmap Factory` and set the `Background` to `Bitmap bg`. This wasn't the solution for me. Also, the background I am trying to reach has been placed in the drawable folder, with an all lowercase name, as a .png. Also, I have build, rebuilt, and cleaned the project--same error. Help?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12523005/how-set-background-drawable-programmatically-in-android

Comment: I have already seen that one, irrelevant to me as my target build for the app is android 4.1

Comment: you just have to do it in this way getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ready)

Comment: try setBackgroundResouce(R.drawable.bg)

Answer (score 2):

`R.(anything).(anything)`

is not the specific object, its the address to where the resource resides from perspective of your compiled resources. It is not the drawable, when you use this id with respect to your context APIs you can get a drawable from that id.

What you want is

```
(View).setBackgroundResouce(id)
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackgroundResource(int)

What you are using is http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackground(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)

Which is expecting a drawable. Read the APIs to understand how and when to use them.

Comment: Tried `relativeLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg);` didn't work

Comment: didn't work doesn't tell us anything. You must be specific. If it didn't work then its an ENTIRELY different reason from the APIs that you are using. Chances are its something wrong with your code. Add logs and debug it to figure it out. Your main question was answered, ideally you should close the question and debug the rest yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Use setBackgroundResource() method instead. Try the following code:

```
relativeLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg);
```

Or try the following:

```
Drawable drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.bg);
relativeLayout.setBackground(drawable);
```

Comment: The first one doesn't exceed the minimum SDK requirement. What is your minimum SDK requirement?

Comment: No, the first one does't. But it doesn't work either

Comment: Is your error in compilation time or after running the project?

Comment: When I actually try to write the code. Before it can even be compiled

Comment: Problem is not in the method. There is happening something different. If you point your cursor on the red symbol in the left side of the statement you will found suggestions. Try to post these...

Comment: There are no errors in android studio when I compile or test. The background change simply does not take place `onClick`. Even after trying all of these suggestions above. Does anybody have any more ideas?

Comment: Is bg (your background resource) a xml file? Then post the xml code of bg. The problem is happening with bg.

Comment: No, my background is a png in the drawable folder

Comment: Check the message in chat.

Answer (score 0):

setBackground takes Drawable and not resource id. When you write R.drawable.bg it will return the resource id (int).

So setting background using the image defined in resources can be done in two ways,

using setBackground

```
relativeLayout.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.bg))
```

using setBackgroundResource

```
relativeLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg);
```

Comment: as @JoxTraex mentioned *didn't work doesn't tell us anything. You must be specific. If it didn't work then its an ENTIRELY different reason from the APIs that you are using. Chances are its something wrong with your code. Add logs and debug it to figure it out.*

Comment: Sorry about that, it has been getting to me for a while now. Everything is rigged up correctly on the code side, but I am wondering if the `relativeLayout` has to have a predefined background int he xml, even if it just is `android:background="#ffffff"`

Comment: Any ideas if this is the case?

Comment: no it is not required to have any predefined background it app. You can set directly using code as well. Check your logcat there must be some error mentioned.