# Setting android:background / android:src programmatically

Tags: android

I need to set two attributes like in a xml:

```
<ImageButton
     android:id="@+id/btn_friendsMainMenu"
     android:src="@drawable/general_btn_header_friendlist"
     android:background="@drawable/ripple"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

As you see, there is a background and an src attribute. How do I set BOTH programmatically?

I only know of one: Which one is it? And what is the other one?

```
 btnBack.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Drawable.thebook_backbutton);
```

Comment: You can use this methods:
imageButton.setImageResource();
imageButton.setBackgroundResource();

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How set background drawable programmatically in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12523005/how-set-background-drawable-programmatically-in-android)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [**`setImageResource()`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView#setImageResource(int)) to set **`android:src`** to your `ImageButton`

> **`setImageResource()`** Sets a `drawable` as the content of this `ImageView`.

**SAMPLE CODE**

```
btnBack.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_camera);
```

Use **`setBackgroundResource()`** to set **`android:background`** to your `ImageButton`

**SAMPLE CODE**

```
btnBack.setBackgroundResource(R.color.colorAccent);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.some_bg_res); // for setting background 'android:background'
imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.some_res); // for setting src 'android:src'
```

Answer (score 2):

you can do it by this code:

```
private void initView() {

        rootLayout =new LinearLayout(this);
        rootLayout.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.layer_5));
        imgLogo=new ImageView(this);
        imgLogo.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.splash_logo));

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
             350,
             350);


        imgLogo.setLayoutParams(params);
        rootLayout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        rootLayout.addView(imgLogo);
        setContentView(rootLayout);
    }
```

and call initView method in your onCreate

Answer (score 0):

[`setImageResource()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView#setImageResource(int)) is for `android:src`. ImageButton inherits it from ImageView.

```
btnBack.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.drawable_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

`setBackgroundResource()` sets the background - it differs from `setBackground()` by taking a ressource id (as int) as input.

I am fairly sure `setImage()` is the method setting the 'src' attribute in xml. It also comes in some different variants. If you want to set a drawable as in your example use `setImageDrawable()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can set image to ImageView programatically in Android please use bellow like of code.

```
imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.android_image3);
```

Answer (score 0):

> android:src is set with setImageResource()

and

> android:background is set with setBackgroundResource()

**In code**

```
ImageButton btn = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.btn_friendsMainMenu);
btn.setImageResource(R.drawable.general_btn_header_friendlist)
btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ripple)
```

> ImagResource will be on top of the BackgroundResource.

Answer (score 0):

There are already true answers but a better approach would be to put this attributes in styles.xml to and give that style to the buttons you want to use to increase clarity and reduce the number of lines you have to write. When your application gets bigger, setting everything from activity/fragment will become unmaintainable.

If your only goal is to change it in the code then take a look at this.

[How to programmatically set style attribute in a view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2016249/how-to-programmatically-set-style-attribute-in-a-view][1])

Answer (score -1):

```
ImageButton btn = (ImageButton)findViewbyId(R.id.img_btn)

btn.setImageResource(R.drawable.image)    
btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ripple)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.