# How to fix programmatically round corners buttons on android?

Tags: android, material-design, android-button, material-components, material-components-android

I am going to want to rounded corners on button like this below code

```
        button.setWidth(buttonWidth);
        button.setHeight(buttonHeight);
```

How to define rounded buttons with java code, no xml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [Material Components for Android](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android).

Just add the dependency:

```
implementation ‘com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0’
```

Add the [`MaterialButton`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/button/MaterialButton.html#setCornerRadius(int)) in your layout:

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
   ....
   style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton"
   app:cornerRadius=".."
   app:strokeColor="@color/colorPrimary"/>
```

and use the method [`setCornerRadius`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/button/MaterialButton.html#setCornerRadius(int)).
Something like:

```
button.setCornerRadius(..);
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd make an xml drawable with the rounded rect background you want (make sure to use a state list drawable if you want it to hilight when pressed) and set it as the background. Setting it as the background is just a setBackgroundDrawable call.

Comment: I did like this  "button.setBackground(R.drawable.score_background);"   but not aplied

Answer (score 0):

Just set your theme to MaterialComponents. Note that this will mess up your current theme though.

https://learntodroid.com/how-to-create-rounded-corners-for-a-button-in-android/ may be another option.

Answer (score -1):

First create a background:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item android:state_pressed="true" >
    <shape android:shape="rectangle"  >
        <corners android:radius="3dip" />
        <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#5e7974" />
        <gradient android:angle="-90" android:startColor="#345953" android:endColor="#689a92"  />            
    </shape>
</item>
<item android:state_focused="true">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle"  >
        <corners android:radius="3dip" />
        <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#5e7974" />
        <solid android:color="#58857e"/>       
    </shape>
</item>  
<item >
   <shape android:shape="rectangle"  >
        <corners android:radius="3dip" />
        <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#5e7974" />
        <gradient android:angle="-90" android:startColor="#8dbab3" android:endColor="#58857e" />            
   </shape>
</item>
```

and then:

```
button.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.ready));
```

this answer is based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6054562/how-to-make-the-corners-of-a-button-round) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12523005/how-set-background-drawable-programmatically-in-android) link.