# How do I change binding on button click to different drawable icon

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, binding

I have a "save" option on my CardLayout, where a user can click "save" and it saves into another fragment.

When clicking "save", it should change the drawable icon "heart" to another drawable. At the moment, I have successfully changed the text when clicking "save" (shown below), but I'm not sure how to change a drawable.

```
            binding.saves.setOnClickListener {
                val exist = dbHandler.getTask(task.id)
                if(exist) {
                    Toast.makeText(itemView.context, "Activity removed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show()
                    binding.saves.text ="Save"
                    dbHandler.deleteFavorite(task);
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(itemView.context, "Activity added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show()
                    dbHandler.addFavorite(task);
                    binding.saves.text ="Saved"
                }
            }
```

`binding.saves.text ="Saved"` changes my `android:text="@string/save"` in XML below.

My XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="0dp"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white"
    app:cardCornerRadius="0dp"
    app:cardElevation="0dp"
    app:cardMaxElevation="3dp"
    app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="true"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    tools:context="ui.CardLayout">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/idActivityName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:text="@string/placeholdertasktitle"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/idActivityDescription"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/idActivityName"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
            android:drawablePadding="2dp"
            android:text="@string/activitydescription"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            tools:ignore="UnknownId" />


        <View
            android:id="@+id/divider"
            android:layout_width="380dp"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/idActivityDescription"
            android:layout_alignStart="@id/idActivityName"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="false"
            android:layout_centerVertical="false"
            android:background="#EDEDED" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linLayout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/divider"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/divider"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/divider"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal">


            <Button
                android:id="@+id/saves"
                style="@style/cardbutton"
                android:layout_width="110dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/cardbutton"
                android:contentDescription="@string/saves"
                android:stateListAnimator="@null"
                android:text="@string/save"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="#595959"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                app:icon="@drawable/ic_saves_blank"
                app:iconGravity="start"
                app:iconTint="#595959" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/calendar"
                style="@style/cardbutton"
                android:layout_width="110dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/cardbutton"
                android:contentDescription="@string/saves"
                android:stateListAnimator="@null"
                android:text="@string/calendar"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="#595959"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                app:icon="@drawable/ic_calendar"
                app:iconTint="#595959"
                app:iconGravity="start"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/copyactivity"
                style="@style/cardbutton"
                android:layout_width="110dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/cardbutton"
                android:contentDescription="@string/saves"
                android:stateListAnimator="@null"
                android:text="@string/copy"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="#595959"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                app:icon="@drawable/ic_copytext"
                app:iconGravity="start"
                app:iconTint="#595959" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

What I have tried:

1. Binding.saves.image ="drawable1" etc. but not sure how to change binding.saves.text to an image
2. Changing "Button" to "ImageButton" and using "state selected" etc.

Do I need to change my "button" to "ImageButton" and do it this way? Is there a way to change just the icon and not the text in binding.?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How set background drawable programmatically in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12523005/how-set-background-drawable-programmatically-in-android)

Comment: Unfortunately, no.

Answer (score 0):

in this case only to change the button when clicked,

you can create 2 button (save & saved)

#note : use materialButton to create text and icon inside the same button.

after that, you can implement this code and change it to your needs

```
                        btn_save.setOnClickListener {
                        if (btn_save.visibility == View.VISIBLE) {
                            btn_save.visibility = View.GONE
                            btn_saved.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                            btn_save.drawable
                        } else {
                            btn_saved.visibility = View.GONE
                            btn_save.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                            btn_save.drawable


                        btn_saved.setOnClickListener {
                        if (btn_saved.visibility == View.VISIBLE) {
                            btn_save.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                            btn_saved.visibility = View.GONE
                            btn_saved.drawable
                        } else {
                            btn_saved.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                            btn_save.visibility = View.GONE
                            btn_saved.drawable
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the button icon to another drawable reference if you change the `Button` to the new `MaterialButton` in the XML.

After that, when you need to change the icon:

```
binding.saves.setIconResource(R.drawable.heart)
```